# Ajax & Laravel 8: select term + onchange event = show cost in input type number

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to dynamically change `<input type="number" name="SLACost" readonly>` based on `<select name="SLATerm">` option

[image]

A table (in DB) that contains:

- SLATerms.
- SLACost.
- SLADeduction

that should be fetched in the "Add new KPI Invoice" form.

I created a function in the controller to fetch the data as json:

```
/**
** KPI API
**/
public function fetchSLA()
{
    $kpiTerms = KPITerms::all();
    return response()->json([
        'SLATermData' => $kpiTerms, // SLATermData is the name that will be used in Ajax.
    ]);
}
```

created a url for ajax to fetch in the **web.php** as `Route::get('kpi/fetch/sla', 'fetchSLA')->name('kpi.fetchSLA'); // The API for fetching SLA as json`

Then went ahead and created the ajax request `GET`

```
function fetchSLA() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "/management/kpi/fetch/sla",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                // console.log(response.SLATermData);
                $("select[name='SLATerm']").change(function() {
                    $("input[name='SLACost']").val(response.SLATermData);
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Obviously, `SLATermData` will fetch the entire data as json and print it in the SLACost input, it shows as `[onject object object]`

I tried to do this:

```
$("select[name='SLATerm']").change(function() {
    $("input[name='SLACost']").val(response.SLATermData.SLACost);
});
```

I thought that adding `SLACost` after `response.SLATermData` will do the trick.

What's missing here?

Comment: _"What's missing here?"_ - the most basic debugging attempts. If you don't know what the structure of `SLATermData` actually is - then log it to the console, and inspect it.

Comment: I am guessing that `KPITerms::all()` will return an array, or some sort of collection? Then you would need to loop over that, or access one element of it via index first of all.

Comment: Correct, it returns an array. This is how the structure looks: https://snipboard.io/5Shk6i.jpg

Comment: Then you would have to loop over those (or use an array method), to find the item that corresponds to the selected SLATerm first of all now. But you should rather change your API - requesting all the data over and over again, as you are currently doing each time the selected option changes, is redundant to begin with. You should pass the selected SLATerm _to_ your API - and then return the matching record from your database only, and not all of them.

Comment: @CBroe I got it working, may you please provide a best practice for a better code when I post the answer? If you don't mind

Answer (score 0):

So I made an ajax request to both SLATerm and SLACost and looped through the requested data. Then I made an `if statement` within the loop to change the `SLACost` based on the `SLATerm` selected.

```
function fetchSLA() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "/management/kpi/fetch/sla",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                $.each(response.SLATermData, function (key, value) {
                    $("select[name='SLATerm']").change(function() {
                        if ( $("select[name='SLATerm']").val() == value.SLATerm ) {
                            $("input[name='SLACost']").val(value.SLACost);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

And here is the Laravel controller for the API:

```
/**
    ** KPI API
    **/
    public function fetchSLA()
    {
        $kpiTerms = KPITerms::get(['SLATerm' => 'SLATerm', 'SLACost' => 'SLACost']);
        return response()->json([
            'SLATermData' => $kpiTerms, // SLATermData is the name that will be used in Ajax.
        ]);
    }
```

Now That I got it working, I'm trying to figure out how to clean the code.

As CBroe mentioned in the comments:

> you should rather change your API - requesting all the data over and
> over again

Which I am trying to do.